# How can I convert .har requests to HTTP string?

Tags: http, perl, lwp, lwp-useragent, har

I'd like to convert requests in .har file ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.har)) to their string version for use with [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP). Is there a tool that does it already?

Specifically I'd like to be able to generate the string in order to parse it like this:

```
my $str = har_to_string($har);
my $r = HTTP::Request->parse( $str )
```

See docs [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/OALDERS/HTTP-Message-6.18/lib/HTTP/Request.pm#$r-=-HTTP::Request-%3Eparse(-$str-)).

I could probably roll my own `har_to_string` in Perl, but I'd like a reference to test against.

Comment: Maybe https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Har would be useful?

Comment: @DavidCollins ok - shame on me for not finding and mentioning it.  However it does not convert the entry to a HTTP string I can then parse. I'd still have to create the reques "by hand"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Archive::Har](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Har) has an `entries()` method which returns a list of [Archive::Har::Entry](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Har::Entry) objects. Each Archive::Har::Entry object has a `request()` method which returns a [Archive::Har::Entry::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Har::Entry::Request) containing details of the request that was made.

It's not the string representation that you ask for, but I expect you could use the various methods on Archive::Har::Entry::Request to generate the HTTP::Request object that you want.

(I haven't tried this, I'm just browsing through documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement, so I whipped something up that may serve as a starting point for others:

```
use strict;
use HTTP::Request;
use JSON::PP;
use LWP::UserAgent;

open my $ifh, '<', 'test.har' or die $!;
my $data = join '', <$ifh>;
close $ifh;

my $jpp = JSON::PP->new->pretty;
my $json = $jpp->decode( $data );
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
### [1] prevent LWP::UserAgent from adding its own "User-Agent" header
$ua->agent('');

for my $entry ( @{ $json->{ log }->{ entries } } ) {
    
    my $req_in = $entry->{ request };
    my $req_out = HTTP::Request->new( $req_in->{ method }, $req_in->{ url } );

    for my $h ( @{ $req_in->{ headers } } ) {
        ### [2] prevent HTTP::Headers from messing with the header names
        $req_out->header( ':'.$h->{ name } => $h->{ value } );
    }

    if ( exists $req_in->{ postData } ) {
        $req_out->content( $req_in->{ postData }->{ text } );
    }

    print "Requesting: ".$req_in->{ url }."\n";
    my $res = $ua->request( $req_out );

}
```

Notes for the above:

1. LWP's own "User-Agent" header https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP#NETWORK-SUPPORT
2. Mangled headers https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Headers#NON-CANONICALIZED-FIELD-NAMES